# jQuery Cycle pageAnchorBuilder / jQuery Selectors

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to grab the source of an image with jquery.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="featuredSlideImage">
    <img src="http://apture.s3.amazonaws.com/0000012865c9e9d984b36217007f000000000001.latte%20heart.jpg"/>
</div> <!--featuredSlideImage-->
```

My jQuery Selector is:

```
    return '<li>' + jQuery(slide).children(".featuredSlideImage").html();  + '</li>';
```

which reutrns this:

```
<img src="http://apture.s3.amazonaws.com/0000012865c9e9d984b36217007f000000000001.latte%20heart.jpg"/>
```

I was to just return the source of that, sans the HTML. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert( jQuery(slide).find(".featuredSlideImage > img").attr("src") )
// http://apture.s3.amazonaws.com/0000012865c9e9d984b36217007f000000000001.latte%20heart.jpg
```

gives you just the Image url

test it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/FbAPQ/